# Very slow download speed on Ubuntu 20.04 vs Windows 10

Tags: 20.04

I have an Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot and i have a big problem with internet speed on Ubuntu.

I use https://speedtest.net/ to test my speed connection and on Windows i have 800+ Mbps Download and 500+ Mbps Upload, but on Ubuntu i have 40+ Mbps Download and 500+ Mbps Upload. I try different settings like disabling ipv6, use another dns, etc. 
The difference is to big, and if i try do download something on Ubuntu, or to update packages it took to long time. 
What should i do to increase my speed on Ubuntu? I also disabled power saving

Ubuntu Download Speed 40+ Mbps

Ubuntu Upload Speed 500+ Mbps

Windows Download Speed 800+ Mbps

Windows Upload Speed 500+ Mbps

So, the only issue is with download speed. If i try to download something, on Windows is instant, on Ubuntu take very long, hours sometime when on Windows take 2-3 minutes.

I don't use Wifi, i use wired connection (cable)

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3831]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0a:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 [144d:a802] (rev 01)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are using to connect. Is it Wi-Fi or what?

Comment: I update my answer with - I don't use Wifi, i use wired connection (cable)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: yes, i will check and try to use kernel 5.6

Comment: Ok, kernerl 5.6 -> download speed 800+ so this was the problem